How does GDM start Wayland?
Where can I find doc (or source code, if no doc exists) to understand how GDM starts Wayland after choosing a user name and typing the password?
I am trying to reproduce this behavior by logging in “manually” (meaning, in a non-graphical virtual terminal, after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fx) and entering commands. I’d like to know the precise sequence I should use to best approach the behavior that is observed under Wayland when starting it through GDM. I suspect it is non trivial, starting dbus and perhaps other processes before somehow starting a Gnome session, but I can find no official doc about this.
(Similar but much more complex question here.)
